# Proof of Convergence of a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n}$ converges and its limit is $1$. However, I am finding it difficult to prove according to the rules that a converging sequence must obey, that is, sequence $X_n$ tends to limit $X$ if for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $M$ that belongs to natural numbers such that $|X_n-X|<\epsilon$ for every $n\ge M$.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2x}{2x+1}=1$$ Hence it converges

Comment: Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (the first few sections of the are enough) and format your question so that it is more readable.  For example, I expect you are missing some $+$ or $-$ signs...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\left|\frac{n^2 + 1}{n^2 + n} - 1\right| = \frac{n - 1}{n^2 + n} < \frac{n}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{n + 1} < \frac{1}{n}.$$
So in fact you only need to find $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$|\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n}-1|<\epsilon\implies 0<\frac{n-1}{n^2+n}<\epsilon \ $ ; if you choose your $\epsilon$ then find $n=M$ s.t. $\frac{n-1}{n^2+n}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\dfrac{N-1}{N^2 + N} < \epsilon$. Then whenever $n \geq N$ we have $$\left|\frac{n^2 + 1}{n^2 + n } - 1\right| < \epsilon.$$

Hence the sequence converges to $1$.

---

Another way of finding the limit is to divide by $n$ on the top and bottom to get $$\frac{n + \frac{1}{n}}{n+1}$$

And as $n \to \infty$ we have $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{n+1} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your expression: $$\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$ and use the fact that $(1/n)\to0$ and $(1/(n^2+n))\to0$ as $n\to\infty.$